# Controlling an RF remote using Linux and C Programming

Tags: c, linux, usb

I have designed an electronic circuit as follows:-

---

**Components:-**
 Tx/Rx = A-434
 Dec/Enc= HT12E/HT12D ICs
 4 buttons at transmitter and 4 LEDs at reciever

---

**Working:-**
 Its simple. At transmitter side: The four buttons are connected to the encoder. The encoder is connected to a tranmitter. At reciever side: The four LEDs are connected to a decoder. The decoder is connected to a reciever. As the button is pressed at the transmitter side, corresponding LED turns on at reciever. Amazing it works perfect.

---

**Question:-**
 I simply want to remove those four manual input buttons and replace it with a C program in Linux. **How can I utilize the USB interface to control the input to my transmitter cicuit?**

Comment: USB is a horrible set of protocols to get going for something simple like this, and I'd try and bit-bash an RS232 port or a parallel port. If you really, *really* want to use USB, I'd use something like this http://numato.com/8-channel-usb-gpio-module or homebrew something similar with a Microcontroller like an Arduino Due or a Teensy.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into how homebrewed IR receivers/senders work as they're somewhat similar to what you want. 
Some of them are:

- http://www.huitsing.nl/irftdi/
- http://dicks.home.xs4all.nl/avr/usbtiny/
- http://www.usbuirt.com/

If you are really not into microcontrollers and you barely know how to program C and connect to a USB device, the [Velleman K8055](http://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?country=be&lang=en&id=351346) may be an option. This may be a bit overkill but it's good for learning basic IO stuff. You basically plug it into the USB port and use it as a digital switch board which you can program in C. The last time I checked, [libk8055](http://libk8055.sourceforge.net/) worked pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a cheap microcontroller board, e.g. a cheap arduino clone. Or use a USB to parallel port converter.